# No work and all play makes Jack... no boy?

Tags: society, eugenics

> *Since as far as we can think back, society has worked on these principles. We have become spacefarers and colonized many a new world. Every member of society is a productive member of society...*

Excerpt from *The Universal Truth*

---

Since the advent of the G.O.D.<sup>1</sup> (further The Advent), unproductive, misconducting and generally lazy members of society have started to disappear. They go to bed one day, and are gone the very next.
None can fathom how these people are detected, nor how they disappear. But it is clear that only *bad* members of society are, as the Believers<sup>2</sup> put it, *excised*.
Everyone adhering to what society determines what they should do at the current stage of their lives seems to be *safe* (Thus, e.g. a child would go to school and do homework).

---

**Q**: Given The Advent happening to the current-day United States of America what are short-term effects, and how would long-term life change?

For the purpose of this question the rest of the world's population does not count into *society*, thus only the US population is relevant.

<sub><sup>1</sup>G.O.D.: General Overruling Directive</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup>Believers: A group of people that claim The Advent as the proof of divine intervention</sub>

Comment: I'm not sure how far we on Stack Exchange can go with this question.  The answers to these questions are tremendously dependent on how you, as the world builder, define "what society determines."  How does this change as society's views change?  Do all the artists striving to make it all suddenly disapear because society doesn't value up and coming art enough?  Is this only 1000ft views (i.e. "go to school") that matter for purposes of dissapearing, or do the smaller things matter ("you must be striving to get A's in all classes all the time")?

Comment: It seems like there's myriad variations, and that's just the starting conditions.  Everything *will* change in response to this new apparent policy, and for each starting condition, I can think of a myriad list of ways it could go from there.

Comment: Agreed with Cort Ammon. If the Directive was magical or above the common understanding, then the principles would likely be taught and followed religiously. If the Directive is tangible, then people are very likely to revolt against it. For an extremely oversimplified example, think of how lower class Europeans during the Middle Ages were taught and obeyed the rituals of Catholicism but [rebelled against them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protestant_Reformation) when it was revealed that leaders were using them to manipulate the people.

Comment: @Kys While it is only one of the factors for the Protestant Reformation. "Where Protestant reformers enjoyed princely patronage, they were much more likely to succeed." It wasn't just the lower classes waking up to Catholic manipulation. The ruling classes in many regions had a lot to gain.

Answer (score 6):

## Society dies out

Most children contract chicken pox, and are immediately quarantined away from their peers. Then The Advent wipes them out, because they are not going to school. Anarchy quickly sets in because a whole slew of politicians past the general retirement age have vanished as well. People who attempt to start riots or loot during this anarchy also vanish. Society dwindles to nothing.

---

As you can see, it all depends on how specific The Advent is, so it's very difficult to answer your question.

## Babies

Babies and infants are probably safe - there's not really much that society expects of them, and there really are very few things they're capable of doing.

## Children

Say goodbye to your *wunderkinder* - since a child is not "expected" to go to college, precocious children are deleted. But this raises a lot of questions. What about truant children who skip class a few times a month? What about kids who are home-schooled? A kid that breaks a leg and has to stay in the hospital for a month or two may very well disappear. You've definitely lost all developmentally challenged children who are unable to, for example, graduate on time.

## Teens

Young adults in poor families are likely to contribute to their family through working, at the cost of their education. Do the poor live in a nightmare world where they can never have their child stay home and care for them if they get sick?

We start losing people "legitimately" here. Youth participation in crimes disappears. Drugs? Gone. Teen pregnancy? Say goodbye to mommy *and* daddy. As children wrestle with puberty, a culture of *fear* develops, since nobody knows what they should or shouldn't do to stick around. From this point on, your population is emotionally crippled for life.

## College

There's no consensus among "society" in the US on post-secondary education, so let's assume that all paths are "valid" here. Otherwise, you might *literally die* if you dropped out of college! Or the Advent decides that someone in their 30s oughtn't be in school, and a whole bunch of PhD, MD, JD, etc. students suddenly disappear, causing science and medicine to wither and die.

## Adulthood

Unemployment means death. This is really, really bad - our economy is known to fluctuate, and if everyone laid off in the latest recession disappears...as demand for workers returns, employers have to raise wages due to low supply. Inflation runs rampant, causing more recessions and more people disappearing.

Handicapped? You're gone. In the hospital? Might be done for as well, after all you're not working. In this dystopia, people turn to alcohol and drugs, which works great because societal expectations shift if literally everyone is doing it, so people survive. It's not clear if crime would actually disappear, given the nebulous definitions of "criminal" and "job." Is a politician who receives campaign donations taking bribes? Is a driver for Vinny the Butcher employed?

The Amish are wiped out, because they don't do the same thing as society at large. Native Americans, too.

Asexuals, the barren, the homosexual, and the unattractive vanish in droves as the divinely mandated "you must have kids" age rolls around.

## Retirement

Oh, did you not save for retirement? Too bad. Society demands that you must stop working when you are old, which means that a whole bunch of professors, priests, doctors, judges, and politicians suddenly vanish into thin air. Was your President over 65? Better find a new one. In the meantime, all the super old, super sick people are still around, draining medicare resources.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the same culture that people talk about arising in China in the Cultural Revolution. There the reason for vanishing was known, but when any given person might run afoul of the standards was unknown. I'm not Chinese, nor a scholar of such, so I won't claim to speak for their history, but I think you should read that history and use it as the basis for "what happens" in your story.